# Do Christians, Jews and Muslims worship the same God?

Tags: allah, christianity, judaism

I also asked this question [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/8851/christianity-judaism-and-islam-worship-the-same-god) and [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18254/christianity-judaism-and-islam-worship-the-same-god)

**[Judaism](http://judaism.about.com/od/judaismbasics/a/whatdojewsbelieve.htm)**

> Judaism is a monotheistic faith, meaning that Jews believe there is
>   only One God. Often this God is beyond our ability to comprehend, but
>   God is nevertheless present in our everyday lives. How individual Jews
>   choose to understand this manifestation of the divine varies. Some
>   connect with God through prayer, others see the divine in the majesty
>   of the natural world, others may not think about God on a daily basis.
>   Each individual's relationship with God is unique and personal.

**[Islam](http://atheism.about.com/library/FAQs/islam/blfaq_islam_basic.htm)**

> Muslims monotheism is closer to that of Judaism than Christianity,
>   rejecting the Christian concept of a "Trinity." Muslims believe that
>   God, creator of all of existence, is just, omnipotent, and merciful.
>   Muslims also reject the anthropomorphization of God in other
>   monotheistic religions like Christianity or Judaism. For Muslims, God
>   is completely "other" — God does not talk, does not walk and does not
>   do anything like humans.

**Christianity (quoting myself)**

> Christianity isn't as easy to define - in fact there are many
>   religious groups who consider themselves Christian but have very
>   different beliefs.  Some of those are Catholic, Protestant, Christian
>   Scientist, and Rosicrucians.  Very generally speaking, Christians
>   believe in a single God and is a Monotheistic religion.  They
>   generally believe in the trinity which is the God, Jesus, and the Holy
>   Spirit are homoousios (the same substance).

[image: BigThree]

All three believe that their God is the God of Abraham.  Jewish people believe that Christians believe in the same God that they do and Christians also believe that they believe in the same God as Judaism.  Similarly, Jewish people believe that Muslims believe in the same God that they do and Muslims also believe that they believe in the same God as Judaism.  However, Christians do not believe that they believe in the same God as Muslims and many Muslims do not believe that Christians believe in the same God as they do.

To me, I believe that if you believe in one all mighty God then you believe in the same God as I do - but your worship is different.  Do Muslims and Christians believe in the same God?

Comment: @RobinHood.  According to the Jewish belief, their God is not the same God as the Christian God.  Yet the Christians believe their God is the same as the Jewish God.  According to the Christian belief, their God is not the same God as the Islamic God.  Yet the Muslims believe their God is the same as the Jewish God and the Christian God.  You should look up Abrahamic religions.  All three religions are branches of the same tree.

Comment: @oshirowanen Jewish belief is that they believe in the same God as both Islam and Christianity.  Please read Seth J's comments here: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/8851/christianity-judaism-and-islam-worship-the-same-god

Comment: Just to point out, we do not believe He (Allah) is ***Just** omnipotent, and merciful.  We also believe He is the all seeing, The Loving, and Unique, nothing is like unto Him. mercy and omnipotence aren't the only attributes of God.

Comment: related: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/44531/christianity-and-islam

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. It's the same God.

> Say, "O People of the Scripture, come to a word that is equitable
>   between us and you - that we will not worship except Allah and not
>   associate anything with Him and not take one another as lords instead
>   of Allah ." ([Surah Al-e-Imran, verse 64](http://quran.com/3/64))

Essentially, the word "Allah" in Arabic is not a translation for "God." It has more connotations than that; for example, it means a being that is inherently unique, and cannot be feminized (goddess) or pluralized (gods).

Also, Islam elevates the status of Christianity and Judaism ("ahlul kitab") because they *are* sourced from the same source -- the same One God (Allah) -- albeit that Islam claims to be corruption-free, while stating that the latter two were corrupted by the hands of humankind.

Comment: You might also want to quote ayaat about rabbu Musa wa Haroon, or how Allah said to Musa (as) I am Allah and the ayaat about Ibrahim (as)'s Lord.

Comment: @Ansari maybe you should right an answer of your own- variation is good on a Q and A site plus, it will bring up ours stats on Area 51

Comment: "Islam claims to be corruption-free". More correctly, Islam claimed to be so at the time of the prophet, but it doesn't mean what we have today is also corruption free. IIRC, there is a famous hadith from the prophet that says *there is no pitfall that Jews fall in and Muslims will not fall in*.

Comment: @Kaveh please feel free to bring this up in chat or a separate question. Islam claims to be corruption free *for all time,* and there are many Islamic sciences to back this up.

Comment: No, the verse is misquoted,The truth is that it just calls the Ahle Kitab to the absolute truth which is in their scriptures without regard to their actual beliefs, Moreover Allah just calls the Ahle Kitab to worship one God alone which they have ceased doing.

Comment: For cross reference; Christianity comes to the opposite conclusion: [Do Christians and Muslims worship the same God?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/989)

Comment: @Kaveh you misquote the hadith, it means that muslims will follow the jews and christians in their mistakes, but it does not mean every muslim, only generally that it will happen. This is clarified by many ahadeeth that state that even until the last day a group will stay on the straight path.

Comment: the question asks whether they worship the same god and not whether they believe in one god. please refer [to my answer](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/10070/940) where I have discussed your answer.

Comment: This answer would be vastly improved if it addressed whether the concept of the trinity (subscribed to by about 98% of modern professing Christians) and/or of the divinity of Jesus (subscribed to by about 99% of modern professing Christians) precludes someone from worshiping the same God as the God of Islam.

Comment: I appreciate that, but now it's not very straightforward. The question asks, "Do Christians [...] and Muslims worship the same God?" The answer begins with "yes" but then concludes by saying that the God affirmed by 98% of Christians is not Allah. That's confusing.

Answer (score 8):

I came across this verse today - it answers the question in the title pretty directly (emphasis mine):

> And do not argue with the People of the Scripture except in a way that is best, except for those who commit injustice among them, and say, "We believe in that which has been revealed to us and revealed to you. **And our God and your God is one; and we are Muslims [in submission] to Him.**" [al-'Ankabut:46](http://quran.com/29/46)

Of course this is broad and doesn't address nuances, but there it is.

Comment: the verse does not mean that we worship the same God, it just conveys the message that all of us have only one God. Surah Kafiroon directly makes the distinction , i.e , I dont worship what you worship...

Comment: @Islam surah al-kaafiroon is for pagans not for people of the book. So if it says "I worship that which you do not" it means I worship Allah, and your worship idols. It does not refer to the people of the book.

Comment: @لَاإِلٰهَإِلَّاالله yes you are correct but above verse in the answer does not say that we worship the same God, it only says our god is one.

Comment: @Islam, I think this is a common way of saing two things are the same thing in Arabic.

Answer (score 4):

In Islam, the definition of God is in [Sura Ikhlas](http://quran.com/112):

> Say, "He is Allah , [who is] One, Allah , the Eternal Refuge. He
>   neither begets nor is born, Nor is there to Him any equivalent."

So we Muslims believe in Allah who is:

- One and Only
- The Eternal
- Neither begets nor is born
- There is nothing like Him

Comment: This only indirectly answers the question. It would be better to add sources (primarily Islamic sources) which evaluate whether Judaism and/or Christianity meet these criteria.

Answer (score 2):

Jews, Christians and Muslims all believe in the same God according to Muslims belief. There is no contradiction in this regard. Islam do believe that Ibrahim, Moses, Jesus and along many other were valid prophet of Almighty Allah but they were there only for that time. Prophet Muhammad was there for rest of the time and is the final prophet of God. Some of the indication that proves Judaism, Christinity and Islam believe in the same God can be proved from the fact that

1. Many of the stories in the Quran are same as in old and new testament. That incudes Adam and Eve, Noha floods, Sulomon and many others
2. Quran recognizes Jesus Christ, Moses and Ibrahim. They have been mentioned in the Quran as valid messenger of God. There is not question about it.
3. Islam abides by Bible to some extent. It can be used as source of guidance if something is not clear enough in Quran.
4. Muslims has utmost respect for Jesus Christ, Moses. When they call their names, they give them special reverence title, that they do not use for any one else but only for the messengers of God.

The following verse in [Quran 5:46](http://quran.com/5/46) talks about Jesus Christ.

> And We sent, following in their footsteps, Jesus, the son of Mary,
>   confirming that which came before him in the Torah; and We gave him
>   the Gospel, in which was guidance and light and confirming that which
>   preceded it of the Torah as guidance and instruction for the
>   righteous.

The holy Quran about Moses in [7:103](http://quran.com/7/103)

> Then We sent after them Moses with Our signs to Pharaoh and his
>   establishment, but they were unjust toward them. So see how was the
>   end of the corrupters.

[Similarities between Judaim, Christianity and Islam](http://www.zimbio.com/Islam/articles/139/Similarities+between+Bible+Quran+Torah+Common)

Answer (score 2):

There are already nice answers discussing the topic of the question. As linked, I visited the other stackexchange sites on the same question. And I felt to share a summery which is actually an answer to the question.

It seems Judaism thinks, it's the same God they and Muslims are worshiping [link](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14461/1712). But Christianity has gone away from the real concept of God with trinity [link](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/89/1712).

Christianity thinks, they are worshiping the same God as Judaism and Islam. But by rejecting trinity, the do not fully recognize the real God.

And as you can see, Islam holds the view all three religions are from same God, Allah. The Jewish idea of God remains alright with possible distortions in other rulings. But in the case of Christianity, the idea of God became distorted with trinity committing the grave sin of Shirk.

Answer (score 1):

**No**

---

First we need to understand what is God before judging whether we worship the same God or not, Allah clearly defines God in Surah Ikhlas:

> Say: He is Allah, the One and Only; [1] Allah, the Eternal, Absolute;
>   [2] He begetteth not, nor is He begotten; [3] And there is none
>   comparable unto Him.

Hence any religion which violates the above definition of God does not worship Allah but their own model of Allah. Only Jewish religion is compatible with the above definition of God.

Theologically Chalcedonian (Trinitarian) creed believes in Jesus's divinity hence practically they don't worship the same God as defined in Surah Ikhlas. The Quran explicitly calls the Christians disbelievers on account of taking Jesus as God:

> Surely, disbelievers are those who said: "Allah is the third of the
>   three (in a Trinity)." But there is no Ilah (god) (none who has the
>   right to be worshipped) but One Ilah (God -Allah). And if they cease
>   not from what they say, verily, a painful torment will befall on the
>   disbelievers among them. Al-Maeda, Chapter #5, Verse #73

But there are a few minority Christian sects like Universal Church, Mormonism etc which don’t believe in the divinity of Jesus and hence worship Allah who revealed the Injeel. Jews worship the lord of Bani Israel which in none but Allah hence they worship the same God as Muslims. Moreover Jews themselves consider Christians to be idolaters (Avodah Zarah) while they consider Muslims to be monotheists (Rambam in Sefer Qedusha, Hilkhot Maakhalot Asurot 11:7 ) having share in the hereafter.

Many people would cite the following verse to claim that Muslims and Christians worship the same God, When Allah says the following :

> Say, "O People of the Scripture, come to a word that is equitable
>   between us and you - that we will not worship except Allah and not
>   associate anything with Him and not take one another as lords instead
>   of Allah ." (Surah Al-e-Imran, verse 64)

The truth is that it just calls the Ahle Kitab to the absolute truth which is in their scriptures without regard to their actual beliefs, In fact in the above verse Allah just calls the Ahle Kitab to worship one God alone which they have ceased doing.

Also the following verse is cited for the claim:

> And do not argue with the People of the Scripture except in a way that
>   is best, except for those who commit injustice among them, and say,
>   "We believe in that which has been revealed to us and revealed to you.
>   And our God and your God is one; and we are Muslims [in submission] to
>   Him." al-'Ankabut:46

Here again Allah only conveys that our God is one without clarifying whether we worship the same God, in fact the presence of such verse indicates that they were not worshipping the same God hence they have to be informed that our God is one God unlike the Christians who believe in the trinity and Godhead of Jesus.

Answer (score 0):

Bismillah Al Rahmaan Al Raheem

As Muslims we believe in the tawheed (oneness) of God. We believe in the tawheed of his rububiyyah (lordship), which means that there is no power or movement except with Allah, we believe in the tawheed of his uluhiyyah (godship), which means that nothing is worthy of worship (ibaadah) besides him and to worship anyone besides him is shirk (shittuf or avodah zarah) and is the one sin that will never be forgiven if one is to die upon it, and we believe in the tawheed of his names and attributes, which means that we affirm and negate for him what he affirms and negates for himself in the quran and what the messenger of God muhammad has said and we do not liken him to his creation but we do not negate his attributes through interpreation. Just like God has an essence so do we but his essence is unlike ours. God is also above his throne above the seven heavens seperate from the creation and in a way that befits his majesty. We believe to call upon anyone other than God, whether it be a prophet, an angel or a dead person is tantemount to shirk (polytheism). We believe that God has no son and was not himself begotten and to believe so is also polytheism. All the prophets were sent to their people to their people to call them to worship God alone. Muhammad is the final prophet and was sent to all of mankind. Whether we are to believe the tora, the psalms or the new testament are corrupted is irrelavent as they have all been abrogated. God has promissed to preserve his final revelation which means he will preserve it from increase or decrease. It do not believe any jew or christian will deny that the old and new testaments have not been changed even if it is only one word. We also believe that the jews went astray by not practicing what was revealed to them and by hiding the truth and we believe that the christians went astray by acting upon ignorance. Islam means submission and it is compulsory for all of mankind including bani israel to submitt to their creater and to worship him alone in accordance with the legislation given to Prophet Muhammad. We are the only religion that has a chain of narration going back to the Prophet and so we can verify what is said to be his words. It is not possible to practice a religion or have a creed that one believes in and is not a 100% sure that it can be authentically linked to the Prophet. We only believe in what is established and we dont just rely on good opinions of people.  Peace be upon those who follow the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is the same God who loves us all, we have God dwelling inside us and that was Jesus' message.
Sometimes we listen to God sometimes we dont.  We learn over time to listen to God and receive his Grace, to recognise God in others. 
Jesus is the son of god, we are **all** children of God! dont let details of religion divide us.  God loves you and me! Gods love transcends rules.  Jesus said his new commandment is to love god and love your neighbour as yourself!   its good news!

Comment: Is this Islamic explanation of the question?

Answer (score -3):

The ancient Hebrew god was YHWH. Modern Hebrew grammarians have tried to translate the name into 'he who causes to be' which is a huge stretch as this god predates Hebrew and Hebrew grammar. To find the origins of YHWH, we must consult the Quran, Surah 71:21-23:

"Noah said, "My Lord, indeed they have disobeyed me and followed him whose wealth and children will not increase him except in loss.
And they conspired an immense conspiracy.
And said, 'Never leave your gods and never leave Wadd or Suwa' or Yaghuth and Ya'uq and Nasr."

The gods Yaghuth & Yauq were 2 of the many gods worshipped by Noah's tribe. Both of these gods contain 4 letters just as YHWH is constructed of 4 letters (tetragrammaton). These names are composed of the name of the god (a theophoric prefix), Ya which is followed by an attribute. Yaghuth means the god, Ya, helps and Ya'uq means the god, Ya, prevents (harm). Similarly the name Yhwh means the god Ya lives and Ya the snake. The best translation of Yhwh would be 'the living snake god'. According to Dr. Richard Steiner, 'hw' is the ancient West Semitic word for snake. (The final 'h' in the name Yhwh is a Hebrew noun suffix). The snake, (nehushtan in the Bible), was Yhwh's sacred animal. Ancient gods were often worshipped in the forms of their sacred animals. For instance, the Canaanite god, El, was worshipped in the form of his sacred animal, the bull.

Noah's tribe lived in Al Judi (Q 11:44) or the rainy place, an ancient designation for Yemen, which experienced a twice yearly heavy monsoon. Yemen early on became very wealthy due to the incense, gold, copper and exotic goods trade. Yemenese tribes as the Minaeans (Ma'in in Arabic & Dedan in the Old Testament), who originated in Hadhramaut, caravanned their goods north and brought their gods with them. Yah (Yhwh) was one of these gods. (Yah is a shortened form of Yhwh. The name Yah can be found in this shortened form throughout the Old Testament). According to Dr. J.A. Montgomery, in his book, Arabia & the Bible, page 134, Yah was another name for the Minaean moon god, Wadd. Like Yhwh, Wadd's sacred animal was the snake.

In the Bible, Yhwh is associated with the moon as he showed himself to Moses on Har Sinai (Moon Mountain) in the plains of Midbar Sin (the wilderness of the moon). Sin was the Akkadian, Assyrian and Babylonian name for their moon gods. The Midianites adopted this god from the Minaeans and passed him on to the early Hebrews. The image of Yhwh as a snake can be seen on the Migdal Synagogue Stone where he is portrayed as an ouroboros (snake consuming his own tail) surrounding the flower of life. This image explains the Garden of Eden story in which Yhwh guards his sacred tree, the tree of life. He is also shown coiling around the 2 trees in the upper corners of his stone (scroll down to image of stone):

http://bennerfarms.com/dutch/

According to 2 Kings 18:4 & Ezekiel 8:10, Yhwh was worshipped in the form of the nehushtan (snake coiled around a pole). This image was still being appealed to in the gospels. In the Gospel according to John 3:14, Jesus compared himself to this image:

"And as Moses lifted up the serpent in the wilderness, even so must the Son of man be lifted up:"

So, YHWH began as an ophic (snake) cult. The origin of the name bears no relationship to the origin of the name Allah (swt), which means "The (only) God.

There is a lot more information on this subject at http://arabianprophets.com. Read the article entitled Serpent Yahweh, YHWH Snake God of Israel.

And Allah (swt) knows best!!!

Answer (score -3):

### Yes. It's the same God.

**Here is how they all connect.**
The Jews where an object oriented people. The greatest of all objects. Is All Objects. So their God is "The All". In Hebrew it is written as (אל) translated as "El" even though it is an Aleph, where we form our letter A. Another form for the name of their God is "Existence". In Hebrew it is written as (יהוה) translated as Lord. Because everyone must follow the Laws of Existence (The Laws of Physics). And also for another reason that it is spoken as the word Lord. The Hebrew word for "Objects" is (אֱלֹהִים). The proof for this is as follows:

**Each of these verses uses a form of the word (Elohim)**

> And now, though thou wouldest needs be gone, because thou sore longedst after thy father's house, yet wherefore hast thou stolen my **gods**? (Gen 31:30 KJV)
>
> With whomsoever thou findest thy **gods**, let him not live: before our brethren discern thou what is thine with me, and take it to thee. For Jacob knew not that Rachel had stolen them. (31:32 KJV)
>
> Then Jacob said unto his household, and to all that were with him, Put away the strange **gods** that are among you, and be clean, and change your garments: (Gen 35:2 KJV)
>
> And they gave unto Jacob all the strange **gods** which were in their hand, and all their earrings which were in their ears; and Jacob hid them under the oak which was by Shechem. (Gen 35:4 KJV)

**Re-translating Gen 1:1 knowing the facts now, We Get**

> In the beginning the objects filled up the Universe and the Earth. (Decoded)

**and Re-translating Gen 1:3 knowing the facts now, We Get**

> and the breath of the objects was a light, and the light existed (Decoded)

Attributing actions to "the All" when it is actions attributed to objects creates much confusion. So the Jews have a confusing God, until they strip down to what is plainly in front of them. Existence.

**However Moses said:**

> You shall have no other objects before my face. (Exodus 20:3 Decoded)

So speaking of Existence became a No No. (If you are under the Rules of The Dictator Moses, and do not have forgiveness.)

**The God of the Muslims**
They have the same God. "The All". "All-ah" means "The God". Cool how the words all work together right?

**The Christians**
The Christians have the same God, however their focus is on:

- What one Thinks (The Father)
- What one Says / Existence (The Son)
- What our Actions Are (The Spirit)

All of these together are still "the All". It is simply categorized to help understand that people LOVE to talk about what they are thinking about.

**The Laws of Physics apply also to Communication**

> "Seek by inquiring but first rule the thought and the righteousness and these things all will be added to you." (Matthew 6:33 Decoded)

Happy living forever. Peace. I love you.